# Dynamic dropdown list in a HTML form

Tags: php, html

I have the following code to create a drop-down list:

```
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Firm Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text"class="input_text_long"  name="name" value="<?php echo $name ?>"/></td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td>Hub Name:</td>
                <select>
                    <option value="">---Select---</option>
                    <?php
                        $list=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hub");
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($list)) {
                    ?>
                    <option value=<?php echo $row_list['name'];?>
                    </option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select>
            </tr> 
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

This, however, does not display any dropdown list. It only displays a text box. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong, please? Or how to create a dropdown box in a form.

Comment: Your html is not formed correctly, first make sure in your table everything is in **<td> </td>** tags, then check your php variable names as @theghostofc suggests. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with this line:

```
<?php echo $row_list['name'];?>
```

It should be:

```
<?php echo $row['name'];?>
```

> Also, your opening `<option>` tag does not have a closing `>`

```
<option value=<?php echo $row['name'];?>></option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `option` tag is wrong.

Right syntax `<option value="VALUE">OPTION NAME</option>`

```
<select>
    <option value="">---Select---</option>
    <?php
    $list = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hub");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($list)) {
          $name = $row['name'];
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $name; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: It still does not give me the list.

Comment: Please `var_dump($row);` in while loop

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
<option value=<?php echo $row_list['name'];?></option>
```

to

```
<option value="<?php echo $row['name'];?>"><?php echo $row['name'];?></option>
```